# Q: Applescript - not passing all files in folder

Tags: file, applescript, directory

I have a question, basically i've wrote "application" in Applescript, and something is quite suspisious.

```
tell application "Finder"

    activate

    set theXMLFolder to choose folder with prompt "ok"

    set numberOfFiles to count of (files in folder theXMLFolder)

    repeat with a from 1 to numberOfFiles

        set theXMLFile to item a of theXMLFolder

        if name extension of theXMLFile is in validExtensions then

            my resetVariables()

            my importXMLFolder(theXMLFile as string) -- import and read XML file

            my writeToExcel() -- convert XML to Excel file

        end if

    end repeat

end tell
```

This is the way how i'm prompting for XML files inside folder. Problem is that when in the folder there are only XML files it works perfect, but in the moment there will be some other files sometimes it doesn't read them all, for ex. it will only find 7 out of 9 files. Is there any way to make it see always and all files?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on the latest version of Sierra

With this code you can bypass the whole “conditional” part of your code

```
property nameExtension : "xml"

set theXMLFolder to choose folder with prompt "ok"

tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files of theXMLFolder whose name extension is nameExtension
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theFiles
        set theXMLFile to item i of theFiles

        my resetVariables()
        my importXMLFolder(theXMLFile as string)
        my writeToExcel()

    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The following *example* **AppleScript** code only acts on *files* having the `name extension` *set* in `validExtensions`, e.g. `xml`, and will act upon every `xml` file based on what's in the `repeat` *loop*, i.e. `--   # Do something.`:

```
set validExtensions to {"xml"}
tell application "Finder"
    set theXMLFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder containing the xml files:"
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of files in folder theXMLFolder)
        set theXMLFile to item i of theXMLFolder
        if name extension of theXMLFile is in validExtensions then
            --  # Do something.
            log (get name of item i of folder theXMLFolder)
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```